# Use table rows as columns on query select MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

I need to make a query (not another table, I'm trying to avoid that please) joining 3 tables. I have one table that specifies ownership schemes, like this:

```
+--------------------------------------------+
|id_scheme | scheme_name | registration_date |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

and another table which contains medical equipment, these have one ownership scheme and a supplier id, and finally another table which contains the suppliers, so, I need a query that can tell me for every supplier, how many equipments i have, and how many of these equipments I have in each ownership scheme category. I don't know how to write a query that use the rows of a table (all my ownership schemes) as a query result columns. So, the query can return something like this:

```
+-----------------------------------+
|supplier|equipments|acquired|leased|
+-----------------------------------+
|Philips |    50    |   13   |  30  |
+-----------------------------------+
```

or like this:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
|supplier|equipments|acquired|leased|commodatum|
+----------------------------------------------+
|Philips |    50    |   13   |  30  |     7    |
+-----------------------------------+----------+
```

and so on.
Please, your help will be very appreciated.

**EDIT**
I put an example of what i want in the image, the equipment and suppliers tables of course have more columns, but i thinks thats all i need to build the query

[image]

Comment: Please give us the detail structure of your other tables with some records. This will help a lot to answer your question.

Comment: thanks, i already put the structure on the image

Comment: you can use case when...SELECT
        DISTINCT
        A.NAME SUPPLIER,
     COUNT(B.ID_EQUIPMENT) EUIPMENTS,
     CASE WHEN B.ID_SCHEMA = 1 THEN COUNT(ID_SCHEMA) END ADUIRIDO,
     CASE WHEN B.ID_SCHEMA = 2 THEN COUNT(ID_SCHEMA) END ARRENDAMIENTO  -- THE LIST GOES ON , CASE WHEN IS THE BASIC IDEA
    FROM
        SUPPLIER_TABLE A
    INNER JOIN
        EUIPMENT_TABLE B
    ON
        A.ID_SUPPLIR = B.ID_SUPPLIER
    INNER JOIN
        OWNERSHIP_TABLE C
    ON
        B.ID_SCHEMA = C.ID_SCHEMA
    GROUP BY
        A.ID_SUPPLIER

Comment: The only problem is that "Adquirido" or "Arrendamiento" or any other ownership schema is not static, i mean, i need this to work dinamically even if I add more schemas and have to change the query everytime, because I am using these tables on a system and the info is always changing (the users can add more schemas as they want to)

Comment: but you give me an idea to solve it with a little programming! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understand your question. Heres me trying to give an answer with an example.

```
SELECT name,author,title from customerstable,classicstable
WHERE customerstable.isbn = classicstable.isbn;
```

This would display a table that has data from two tables (customerstable and classicstable) whenever they share an isbn.
Of course you would change your values with your data. But a more detailed structure would help for a better answer. maybe even the first few rows for each table you are trying to join in a query.

In your database the isbn could be replaced with ids that are the same throughout multiple tables.

Comment: I posted the structure and an example of what I need, thanks